# RESTful .net - POST without Content-Type

Tags: c#, .net, json, rest

Is it possible to have a web service accept json formatted requests without a content-type header?

The POST verb works great when I pass the Content-type: application/json header.  If that is left off then a 400 error is thrown.  I have gone through many questions on here asking why they are getting a 400 back and the answer is the content-type.  So is it possible on the server side to "fill that in" on behalf of the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with a default .NET webstack to do so without some sort of content-header to tell it how to interpret the request. If you wanted to get into the internals of the ASP.NET stack (you can use a reflector app such as ILSpy) you might could find an intercept point, but you'll most likely have to do some custom IIS integration to get the module to intercept the request, possibly even before the ASP.NET stack becomes involved.

For most people it's infinitely easier to get the JSON requesting application to introduce a header.

In addition, I encourage you to start learning how to use Reflector to explore how these stacks work, they really are complex and large and quite extensible, at the cost of engineering (bald guess right now says an inexperienced IIS dev will need approximately 50 hours to engineer this technique, if it can be done neatly).

Comment: I'll have to look into ILSpy and Relector.  It looks like the client is able to use content-type without issue so thankfully I won't have to put any of that into practice this time.  Great stuff to know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WebAPI or ASP.NET MVC? I have a solutions for you, although some might scream at me.

- You could create an attribute that tries to deserialize the request's body into the object you are looking for for that particular action. If it works, then you can pass that in to the parameter list using the RequestContext. Not sure off the top of my head what the exact properties are you'll need to set, but I remember doing something very similar in ASP.NET MVC.

Hope that helps.

P.S. Use JSON.Net, it has a lot of helpful deserialization methods that will make this a breeze.

Comment: Are you sure the attribute would actually be called in this case?  It seems like the server is rejecting it before that part of the code would be reached.

Comment: 400 means bad request. Also the fact that after you put the content-type it works makes me assume it is hitting your code on some level. Even if it doesn't get to your method/action.